# Google Font with closest match to Adobe-Clean

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I have had a design sent with Adobe-Clean as the font. I assume this is part of the paid Typekit font.

Does anyone know the closest font to Adobe-Clean?

This seems to be the font Adobe use across their sites
http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html

[image: Example of Adobe Clean]

Answer (score 3):

"*Ubuntu*" is a free Google font that's pretty close.

[Ubuntu font on Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu)

[image]

Comment: Takes up significantly more space horizontally.